# Python for C4D invalid syntax underneath file path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cinema-4d

Hi does anyone know why I have an error here underneath the t ?:

*SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "'scriptmanager'", line 3
    filepath = r '/Users/luke/Documents/water.numbers.csv'*
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

regards,

import c4d

filepath = r '/Users/luke/documents/water.numbers.csv'

fileobj = (filepath, 'r')

print fileobj.readline ()

Comment: Post the first 10 lines of scriptmanager.py

Comment: Hi Tony,  There's only 7 lines at the moment. many thanks luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is what you want this?

```
1 import c4d
2 
3 filepath = r'/Users/luke/documents/water.numbers.csv'
4             ^
5 fileobj = open(filepath, 'r')
6           ^^^^
7 print fileobj.readline()
                        ^
```

- You had a space between "r" and "'" after "filepath =" which I think would make trouble (line 3).
- You were missing the 'open' for creating a file object (line 5.
- I think Python probably also won't like the space between "readline" and "()" (line 7).

Comment: Thank you Tom thats great that seems to have solved the Issue many thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to help, Luke. Would you want to give my answer a vote and select it as having solved your problem? Thanks.